# Scala collection of strings - a way to output strings without double quotes

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a collection of strings.

When I iterate through the collection (using .map()) to output the values, the string "Lipsum" gets outputed with double quotes

Inside Scala class:

```
case class Container(id: Int, name: String, url: String)
val tags = (i \\ "tags").flatMap{
    tag =>
        tag.as[JsArray].value.map {
            element => Container(element \ "id", element \ "name", element \ "url")
        }
}
```

Inside Template:

```
<div class="item">
    @tags.element.map { item =>
        @item.name
    }
</div>
```

Collection output ( println(item.name) ):

```
List(Container(1957,"Lipsum","/lipsum"))
```

**Current** output of the string looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
"Lipsum"
</div>
```

**Desired** output:

```
<div class="item">
Lipsum
</div>
```

How can I get rid of the double quotes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element \ "name"` gives you a JsValue. `JsString.toString` will add the double quotes.

I'm surprised that `Container(element \ "id", element \ "name", element \ "url")` compiles, but this should work:

```
Container(element \ "id", (element \ "name").as[String], (element \ "url").as[String])
```

Comment: Thanks man, the (element \ "name") already returns play.api.libs.json.JsString